# Could a focused magnetic beam be capable of being the next military weapon?

Tags: electromagnetism

For over two weeks I have been researching magnetism and how you can alter the flow of magnetic field lines. As a teen interested in this  topic I cannot find help from my average science teacher in which I am studying the periodic table and not magnetism yet and he seems to have a lack of knowledge on this highly intriguing topic. All though I have done loads of research I fear rushing into development of a new magnetic super weapon can go awry. I am seeking help from people with the same amount of knowledge on physics as I have.

Could a focused magnetic beam be capable of being the next military weapon?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it's not possible to focus a magnetic field the way you would like to do it.  Static field lines will *always* be farther apart away from the source.  It would be necessary, in essence, to generate the magnetic field at the location of the target in order to have the maximum field strength there.

Maxwell's equations, which describe the electromagnetic field very precisely, make this fact obvious to those who understand the equations.  The equations dealing with the magnetic field state that the divergence of the magnetic field is zero (that is, there are no magnetic monopoles), and that the only sources of the magnetic field are either moving electric charges or changing electric fields.  Static electric fields and magnetic fields *always* get weaker with distance away from their sources.

The only way to obtain a stronger field at a distance is with electromagnetic waves: e.g., microwaves or light waves.  And yes, both light and microwaves have been used in "beam" weapons.  If you would like to understand all this, you'll need to learn calculus and electromagnetism.  There are plenty of free courses available online, such as [https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/] and [https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/].